# Debug error : 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block in Fsharp

Tags: f#

My code :

```
let main _ =

  let t = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int

  for i in 1..t do
    let n = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int

  0
```

And I got errors as following :
The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.

Can you help me ? Thank you very much .

Answer (score 7):

To give some more details on why this is required - in F#, everything (aside from type and module definitions) is expression that has some return value. This even applies to things like `printf` - they still return value, but it is the unit value, written as `()`, which represents a dummy value with no information.

The problem is that `let <var> = <expr>` is not a complete expression, because it does not return anything. The full form is `let <var> = <expr1> in <expr2>`. This assigns the result of `<expr1>` to the variable `<var>` and evaluates `<expr2>` and returns the result. If you're using a line break, you can omit `in`, but you still need some body.

In yor example, the best option is to use `()` as the body, because you're not returning anything useful. You can write this using `in` or using a line break:

```
for i in 1..t do
  let n = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int in ()

for i in 1..t do
  let n = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int
  ()
```

This is not very useful thing to write, because you're not using `n` anywhere, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop, the last statement is a `let`.  Adding a 0 indented to the same level should fix the problem

Comment: Why `0` (zero)? Did you mean `()` (unit)? Finishing the scope inside a for-loop with a value other than unit should produce a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John Palmer . I learned many things . So this's result for the problem :

```
let t = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int

for i in 1..t do
    let n = (System.Console.In.ReadLine ()) |> int

    printf("%d\n") n

    0

0
```

Comment: You can remove the inner 0. The compiler only wants that the last line within the indented scope is an expression; `printf("%d\n") n` is an expression that evaluates to unit value `()`, so the code is already valid with that. In fact, as is, the inner 0 should produce a compiler warning.